# Make scrollviewer not capture control left and control right in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a WPF application where I have defined custom commands that use the key gestures <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>.  My window has a `TextBox` and a `ScrollViewer` and when the `TextBox` has focus <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> move the cursor to the beginning of the next or previous word, which is fine.

But on the `ScrollViewer` it makes the horizontal scroll move as if I had pressed just <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> .  What's the easiest way to allow the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> events to bubble up from my `ScrollViewer` to the Window where the `Command` is defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I got this working by doing the following

```
public class MyScrollViewer : ScrollViewer
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right)
                return;
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

I think the trick is to understand that the event starts at the top and works it's way down.  Then on the way back up each "layer" checks the Handled boolean and if it isn't set to true it will determine if it will do something and set it if it does.  I needed to short circuit this behavior for my shortcuts so that Handled would still be false when it made it's way back up to the Window level.

Answer (score 4):

You must override `ScrollViewer`'s `PreviewKeyDown` event and set `e.Handled = true` and pass on the event to parent using something like `(this.Parent as FrameworkElement).RaiseEvent(e);` if the keys pressed were one of the key combination you assigned to your commands.

Comment: This is the right answer for scroll viewer (in WPF).  The OnKeyDown event doesn't fire on the arrow keys, but this does. Thanks!